# Maven exec in docker container

Tags: java, maven, docker

I have java app that I want to run in docker, here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash procps

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.5.4
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=ce50b1c91364cb77efe3776f756a6d92b76d9038b0a0782f7d53acf1e997a14d
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

COPY docker/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
COPY docker/settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/

RUN mkdir --parents /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Add pom.xml file first only
ADD pom.xml /usr/src/app/

# Perform clean, this way maven will download all dependancies
# and will include them inside image, saving time while running image
# not having to download project`s dependancies every single time
RUN mvn verify clean --fail-never

# Add everything else from the project
# with exception to pom.xml that was already added
ADD src /usr/src/app/src/
ADD resources /usr/src/app/resources/

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
```

My ***mvn-entrypoint.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

mvn package exec:java
exec "$@"
```

Part of my project pom:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now it works fine, if I run it locally using command:

```
mvn package exec:java
```

then I can see my Main class running as expected, but when I build and run this image, I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'java
banyard.automation-reporting_1  | 
[ERROR] ' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0 among available goals exec, help, java -> [Help 1]
```

That i dont really understand how to fix, because I do have 'java' goal specified in my pom above.

Comment: The issue `java
banyard.automation-reporting_1` cause it not a single part it's a combined part which results in the failure.

Comment: Hi, i changed it to single image name, without '-' or '.' but unfortunate it is still same error, thank you.

Comment: Try to remove the execution goals you have defined in your pom file...

Comment: Still same error unfortunately.